# Finding the dimensions of an array through assembly

Tags: c, assembly, multidimensional-array, x86, reverse-engineering

I have an assignment to reverse engineer the assembly to find the values of R, S, and T in the following code. Assume that R, S, and T are constants declared with `#define`.

```
long int A[R][S][T];
int store_ele(int h, int i, int j, long int *dest)
{
   A[h][i][j] = *dest;
   return sizeof(A);
}
```

When compiling this program, GCC generates the following assembly code (with -O2):

```
 store_ele:
    movslq    %esi, %rsi          //%rsi = h
    movslq    %edi, %rdi          //%rdi = i
    movq    (%rcx), %rax          //moves the value from %rcx to %rax
    leaq    (%rdi,%rdi,4), %rdi   //%rdi = 4 * i + i
    leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,4), %rcx   //%rcx = 4 * h + h
    movslq    %edx, %rdx          //%rdx = j
    leaq    (%rcx,%rdi,4), %rcx   //%rcx = 4 * %rdi + %rcx  = 4 * (4 * i + i) + (4 * h + h) 
    addq    %rcx, %rdx            //adds something to j
    movq    %rax, A(,%rdx,8)      //moves some value
    movl    $1120, %eax           //%eax = 1120
    ret                           //returns %eax
```

I want to ask if what I am understanding about the assembly is right and any tips or assistance is appreciated!

Edit: I don't know what it is called but our prof. defines `movq: source, destination` and other similar assembly instructions where the first argument is source and second is destination

Edit 2: Biggest issue is how do I find the values of the three constants just based on the assembly. I think

```
movq   %rax, A(,%rdx,8) //moves some value
movl   $1120, %eax      //%eax = 1120
ret                     //returns %eax
```

Is going to play the main role in finding out what it does but I don't know what to do with it.

Edit 3: Don't know if I should put the answers, but if someone might have same problem, I got T = 5, S = 4, and R = 7 where R = 1120/T*S*8 and I got T and S from matching coefficients from the help I got from this thread.

Comment: What register carries what depends on the ABI. I assume this is Linux (System V ABI, if I remember correctly)? If so, please add a tag for the platform (e.g. Linux, Windows, OS X, etc.). Also, what are the `#define`s for `R`, `S` and `T`?

Comment: Just describing what each instruction does is only the first step. That can be found easily from the databook/instruction set manual. Next step is to compose semantical units. What is your **specific** problem?

Comment: As a sidenote: enabling optimisation for debugging/analysis is a very bad idea!

Comment: FWIW, `movq source, destination` is AT&T syntax. Intel syntax has the operands reversed: `mov dest, source`.

Comment: @Olaf: totally disagree.  When the code is this simple, un-optimized code is just full of noise of storing/reloading.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I agree with Olaf. Unoptimized code may have some more "noise", but it can much more easily be correlated with the original code, especially because of those load/store sequences and the omission of optimization tricks. Only someone who is used to reading a lot of assembler will consider optimized code easier to read. But not a beginner. In my humble opinion.

Comment: `movq  (%rcx), %rax` moves the value that `rcx` points to into `rax`. So I'm guessing that `rcx` is the `dest` parameter. Also, if you've been given the values of `R`, `S` and `T` then you really need to add those to the question.

Comment: If you factorise `1120` the size of the array (2*2*2*2*2*5*7), this should give you clue.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: that's fair, all those LEAs are less clear than imul with an immediate would be.  gcc's cost model considers imul more expensive than it is on modern Intel, and will sometimes use more than one LEA (or maybe even more than two LEAs?).  Generally, though, `-Og` (optimize for debugging) is a good bet, because the actions of each source line are basically still present in the asm.

Comment: @user3386109 I am suppose to find R,S,T

Comment: @WeatherVane would making   1120 = (2*2*2*2*2*5*7) = 4 * (4 * i + i) + (4 * h + h) + j be the right approach?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I guess it depends on the compiler too. I usually don't use GCC, and the debugging/optimization options for C++Builder or Clang are sometimes different. For my favourite language, Delphi, they are totally different.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Much what Rudy wrote. Optimised code can extremely obfuscate the high-level operations. With a modern compiler this is even for an experienced developer with good Assembler-knowledge a pain. For a beginner it is often near impossible. And yes, `-Og` might be a good compromise. Never tried it on x86, though.

Comment: @JMei maybe, there are various permutations. Remove the `sizeof(long int)` from that first.

Comment: @Olaf: sure, if you're looking at a complex function.  We're talking about trivial functions, like `int foo(int a, int b) { return a * b; }`, I'd rather look at a [two-instruction function](https://godbolt.org/g/32gWU7) than a whole bunch of copying to the stack and back.  With `-fverbose-asm` gcc will even comment asm instructions with the C variable name for the values invovled.  (In optimized code it's often tmp1234..., though).  Still, it's worth compiling both ways and looking at whichever one is easier.  At -O0, you don't know if a store is happening because it's needed or not...

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean by remove the sizeof long int? the j?

Comment: I mean that some of the powers of two are from the variable type's size, not the array dimensions, so take them out  - either `2*2` (32-bit) or `2*2*2` (64-bit). If 64-bit as suggested in other comments that leaves `2*2*5*7`

Comment: @WeatherVane So the array dimensions should 2* 2* 5* 7 = 4 * (4 * i + i) + (4 * h + h) + j after removing the 64-bit?

Comment: @JMei I am just making suggestions to explore. Assuming that none of the dimension is `[1]` (fairly pointless) that leaves `A[4][5][7]` or `A[2][10][7]` or `A[2][5][14]`, or the 5 other perms if you switch them around. So you have 6 x 3 possible configurations.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, I see what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterCordes: `-O0` generates simple, recognisable patterns. Optimised code breaks these patterns.

Comment: @JMei: The best place for answers on Stack Overflow is in Answer posts.  It's totally fine to post your own answer on your own question, to add to the existing answers.  You could also edit my answer to add a section with the boring details about what the numbers actual are, but it's probably best to post it in your own answer.  (esp. so future readers can see that you posted the numbers yourself after understanding the method to solve your own homework, rather than having them given in someone else's answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's x86-64 AT&T syntax (mnemonic source, dest), with the x86-64 System V ABI (first arg in rdi, see this [approximate summary of that calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), or find links to better ABI docs (including the official standards) in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

What you're calling "functions" are assembly instructions.  Each one assembles to a single machine instruction.

---

Hint: your comments are wrong about which arg is which.  Check the ABI for arg-passing order.

Since you know the declaration is `long int A[R][S][T]`:

`A[h][i][j]` is equivalent to `*(A[h][i] + j)`, where `A[h][i]` is an array type (with size `[T]`).  Applying this recursively, `A[h][i][j]` is equivalent to `*(base_pointer + S*T*h + T*i + j)` (where base_pointer is just a long*, for the purposes of C pointer math which implicitly scales by sizeof(long) in this case).

You seem to be on the right track working out how the LEAs are multiplying, so you can find T, then use that to find S (by dividing the factor for h).

Then to find R, look at the function return value, which is `R*S*T * sizeof(long)`.

`sizeof(long)` in the x86-64 System V ABI is 8 bytes.  The offset into the array is scaled by 8 bytes, too, of course, so don't forget to factor that out when getting your S and T values.

Comment: I don't really understand the first part to find T, but for R, you're saying that 1120 = R*S*T * 8(sizeof(long))

Comment: @JMei: yes.  To find T, look at the store into `A(,%rdx,8)`.  RDX is the sum of a few things.  Look at which part can be traced back to some multiple of `j`, and that's your T.  (The scaling by 8 (sizeof(long) is applied at this point, with the scale factor in that addressing mode which uses RDX as the index, so you don't have to worry about it before that.)

Comment: From what I can back track, rdx = j + %rcx = j + (4 * 5i) + 5h. and the movq %rax, A(,%dx,8) moves the address of rax into the second one?

Comment: I tried to edit my prev comment to combine both my comments but it didn't let me. //So if it try to match what I back tracked into the template you put (base_pointer + STh + Ti + j), T = 5, S = 4, and to find R, RST*8 = 1120, R = 1120/(5*4*8) = 7?

Comment: what are you doing at this part "Since you know the declaration is long int A[R][S][T]:

A[h][i][j] is equivalent to *(A[h][i] + j), where A[h][i] is an array type (with size [T]). Applying this recursively, A[h][i][j] is equivalent to *(base_pointer + S*T*h + T*i + j) (where base_pointer is just a long*, for the purposes of C pointer math which implicitly scales by sizeof(long) in this case)."

Comment: @JMei: I'm trying to explain how the `[]` operator works in C, and that `arr[x]` is exactly equivalent to `*(arr + x)`, even if `arr` is a multi-dimensional array.  So you can peel back the indexing and write it as a simple sum of pointers and scale factors.  google `c brackets pointer arithmetic` for more stuff.