# Finding P and Q in assembly matrix

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I have to use the assembly code to find the value of P. How do I read this?
I am not quite sure how to begin. If anyone could help me by either going through it step by step or just explaining it to me. Either way would be a big help

in C:

```
#define P ?
#define Q ?
int mat1[P][Q];
int mat2[Q][P];
void copy_element( int i, int j) {
     mat1[ i ][ j ] = mat2[ j ][ i ];
```

in assembly:

```
copy_element:
    movslq %edi, %rdi
    movslq %esi, %rsi
    movq   %rsi, %rax
    salq   $4, %rax
    subq   %rsi, %rax
    addq   %rdi, %rax
    movl   mat2(,%rax,4), %ecx
    leaq   (%rdi, %rdi, 4), %rdx
    leaq   0(, %rdx, 4), %rax
    addq   %rax, %rsi
    movl   %ecx, mat1,(,%rsi,4)
    ret
```

My full try:

```
copy_element:
    movslq %edi, %rdi             ?(rdi = i)
    movslq %esi, %rsi             (rsi = j)
    movq   %rsi, %rax             (rax = j)
    salq   $4, %rax               (rax = 16j)
    subq   %rsi, %rax             (rax = 15j)
    addq   %rdi, %rax             (rax = 15j + i)?
    movl   mat2(,%rax,4), %ecx    (ecx = 60j + 4i)?
    leaq   (%rdi, %rdi, 4), %rdx  (rdx = 5i)
    leaq   0(, %rdx, 4), %rax     (rax = 20i)? or maybe (rax = 15j + 21i)?
    addq   %rax, %rsi             (rsi = j + 20i)
    movl   %ecx, mat1,(,%rsi,4)   what?? (? = 64j + 80i)
    ret
```

P = 60 and Q = 80?

or are they P = 15 and Q = 20?

of course both could be wrong

(I am sorry if this question is bothersome or if I didn't do something correctly.)

Comment: Well, do you understand the instructions? Comment the lines with what they do. Work out the formula then compare with the layout of arrays.

Comment: @Jester I am very bad at assembly unfortunately  :/. I understand leaq, addq, and subq and only when it's basic with like three lines of assembly code.

Comment: You might want to double check that assembly code, looks like there are 1 or 2 typos.  For example, we don't `leaq` into `ecx`.  That's not only a size mismatch, but the wrong register, thinking it should be `rdx`.

Comment: @ErikEidt thanks, I have now fixed hopefully everything. Still don't understand much but thanks for the answer and comment :)

Comment: Can you figure our what factor is used for muliplying `j` for the `mat2` expression?  It is doing a fancy shift and subtract sequence!  Start with the shift alone: what does that multiply by?

Comment: My guess would be rsi = j, then rax = j, then you shift with 4 (don't know what that does), you take one j of the shifted variable and then add i to it? then you move the newest version of j, multiplied by 4, to %ecx. Thats what I got @ErikEidt

Comment: Yes, it is doing `(j<<4)-j`.  That shift multiplies by a power of 2.  So study such shifting and then you'll have something like `j×?-j` left to reason out.

Comment: @ErikEidt So I get 15j. Then I have to addq rdi or i (I think) to it. So rax = 15j + i?

Comment: Duplicate of [Reverse engineer array dimensions from code indexing int arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69847322) (except for the exact numbers), but it was only answered in comments.  Near duplicate of [Finding the dimensions of an array through assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39550678) and [Reverse engineer array dimensions / struct layout from compiler asm output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33603082) (although that one spends time on struct layout).  Also [Reverse engineering and interpreting assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67732896)

Comment: @PeterCordes Is my try on the right track? That P = 15 and Q = 20 or am I wrong

Comment: @Jester perhaps? Can anyone shed some light on this situation? I have been trying for long but still have no idea what the answer is

Comment: Since you have accepted Erik's answer we assumed you solved the problem.

Comment: @Jester I am new here and I am adjusting to the rules and format of this site. I have not solved the problem. I have no idea if the answer is P = 15  and Q = 20 or 60 and 80 or something completely else. If someone could give me the answer so I can go through it and understand why the answer is what it is I could perhaps understand Assembly a bit more

Comment: Yes you got the P=15 and Q=20 right. Any questions still?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been trying this for hours since I posted this yesterday. I have been just so confused but I am glad that I understand this correctly, if only the bare minimum. Since you asked does the "leaq   0(, %rdx, 4), %rax" (line 10) give rax a new value. I assume so since 15 and 20 is correct. I was just wondering if it overwrites the previous value or adds on?

Comment: It overwrites `rax`.

Answer (score 1):

The `mat1` expression is on the left of the `=` sign, meaning it is the target of the assignment, while the `mat2` expression is fetching the value to be used in that assignment.

We know that `mat1` will be a memory write, and that first it will have to do a memory read for `mat2`.

We also know that for `mat2` it needs to compute`(j×P+i)×4`, and for `mat1`, `(i×Q+j)×4`.

We also know that `i` is in `edi` and `j` is in `esi` upon function entry.

These facts and the assembly code are sufficient to reason out `P` and `Q`.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but enable optimizations to remove the noise. Also change `int` indexes to the correct type `size_t`

```
        imulq   $100, %rdi, %rax
        addq    %rsi, %rax
        imulq   $10, %rsi, %rsi
        addq    %rdi, %rsi
        movl    mat2(,%rsi,4), %edx
        movl    %edx, mat1(,%rax,4)
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hb54f1x6x

or

```
        leaq    (%rsi,%rsi,4), %rdx
        leaq    (%rdi,%rdi,4), %rax
        leaq    (%rdi,%rdx,2), %rdx
        leaq    (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
        movl    mat2(,%rdx,4), %edx
        leaq    (%rsi,%rax,4), %rax
        movl    %edx, mat1(,%rax,4)
        ret
```

Comment: I think the OP has the assembly output, but not the values of P and Q, which they're trying to find by looking at the assembler.

Comment: @psmears: Correct.  This would only help to simplify the 2nd asm block in the question, where they're compiling their C attempt into asm to compare against the original asm.  But those were already compiled with some optimization level, since they don't spill/reload their incoming stack args.  Using the same compiler with the same `-O1` or something will make asm that's actually the same if you get the right answer.  (Or more similar if it's a different GCC version).

Comment: @psmears yhea, you're right I am only trying to find the value of p and q. My answer atm is p = 15 and Q = 20. I am an absolute noob when it comes to assembly. I did well in datalab but got lost in assembly.